# Trello API - Unauthorized permission request

Tags: api, jsfiddle, trello

I am trying to write a little script to update cards with the amount of time the card has been on the list it is currently on, so we can optimize our throughput. I wrote a little script on jsfiddle that almost works, but I'm getting a "**unauthorized card permission requested**" when trying to use:

```
Trello.post("cards/" + card.id + "/actions/comments", {text: "This card has been in this list for " + ago + " days."})
```

or...

```
Trello.put("cards/" + card.id + "/name", "(" + ago + ") " + card.name);
```

Here is the fiddle, if that helps: http://jsfiddle.net/A3Xgk/2/

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Try request your app token from
https://trello.com/1/connect?key=yourkey&name=your_board_name&expiration=never&response_type=token&scope=read,write

reference:
https://github.com/zmilojko/git-trello

Answer (score 6):

The "unauthorized card permission" that is being requested is the **write permission**

In your [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/A3Xgk/2/), when the "Connect to Trello" window pops up, you'll notice it says

> **The app will be able to:**
>
> - Read all of your boards and organizations
>
> **It won't be able to:**
>
> - Create and **update cards**, lists and boards
> - **Make comments for you**
> - Read your email address
> - See your Trello password

You need to request a token that has **write** permissions, which you can do by changing the `scope` parameter to `Trello.authorize`:

```
$("#connectLink").click(function() {
    Trello.authorize({
        type: "popup",
        scope: { read: true, write: true },
        success: onAuthorize
    });
});
```

(The default value for `scope` in **[the source for client.js](https://trello.com/1/client.coffee)** is `{ read: true, write: false }`)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I'm still getting the "unauthorized card permission" though. I update the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A3Xgk/3/  ... the auth pop up still says it won't be able to update cards or make comments. Any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Oops, n/m... hard refresh :) Thanks again Daniel!

Comment: None of the examples I can find in jsFiddle work anymore.  For instance, the "official" http://jsfiddle.net/nNesx/ does pop up an Authentication window, but the authentication window cannot write the token back to jsFiddle: Unable to post message to http://fiddle.jshell.net. Recipient has origin http://jsfiddle.net.