# Trello API: unauthorized permission requested

Tags: api, python-requests, trello

I'm trying to use the api to get the invitation secret to use it for creating share links. Here's my code:

```
URL = "https://trello.com/1/boards/" + boardid + "/invitationSecret"
query = {
    'key': key,
    'token': token
}
response = requests.request("POST", URL, params=query)
```

On execution, I get 'unauthorized permission requested'. I did checkout [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919354/trello-api-unauthorized-permission-request), but the solutions suggested there don't work for me.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pay, free version can't write/post